# How to detect changes in Component when user has changed something on the view in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to detect the changes when suppose user has changed value for input type(like for radio button,input text,input text area etc.)

```
<input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="mileage"/>
```

I don't want to use (ngModelChange)="detectChanges($event)" to detect the changes coz i need to make it generic so that i can use for whole component's input type

Answer (score 2):

```
<form #myForm>
  <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="mileage" name="xxx"/>
  ...
</form>
```

```
class MyFormComponent {
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm:NgForm;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#template2 also uses this method in an example.

You could also make `mileage` a getter/setter, then you can put code into the setter that is executed when the value changed, but that needs to be done for each property an input is bound to.

You can also add

```
@HostListener('change', ['$event'])
onChange(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
onInput(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

You need to add a listener for every event you might be interested.
There are some differences between browser what events they fire for what edit action. `ngModel` abstracts some differences away which you might need to take care of yourself.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer but Is there any other way than form to detect the changes dirctly with ngModule?

Comment: So you don't want to use `ngModel` at all. I updated my answer.

Comment: Can i use ng-dirty concept to just detect the changes?But using that i am unable to get the original value It still showing me that value is changed

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your last comment. I don't know AngularJS 1.x and `ng-dirty`.

Comment: If you see this below link and open developer tools on browser then you will see when you enter some value in inputtext then ng-dirty in class appers coz of that is shows value is changed http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputtext

Comment: You could use `@ViewChildren(NgModel) myDirectives:QueryList<NgModel>;` and then use these references to subscribe to `ngModelChange`.